# PHP doesn't seem to instantialize any classes

Tags: php, oop, class, autoload

http://pastebin.com/25CwPDB2    <-- Index.php
http://pastebin.com/4ZTvy0kk    <-- /system/Main.php

This seems to happen on both a Windows and Ubuntu 10.10 server.

The script is supposed to output:
"trying to load main"
"Autoloaded class "
"Hello from Main!"

Comment: an error message/ output would help ?

Comment: Maybe you can summarize your code in your post, without all of the comments that are in the pastebin?

Comment: probably because your `ROOTDIR` is pointing to `__FILE__` instead of being `dirname(__FILE__)`? -- ps, I though I commented a lot, holy cow... Is a 3:1 ratio of comment:code necessary?

Comment: I recommend outputting the value of $class inside of your __autoload and viewing the file path you are attempting to autoload.  I'm guessing you need to replace __FILE__ with dirname(__FILE__) as your ROOTDIR.

Comment: @n00b32 @BradChristie @Macy Abbey Yeah, I fixed the __FILE__ to __DIR__ (this isn't the most recent code snippit). There are no errors. I'll fix it in the pastebin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    error_reporting("E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE");
```

this is wrong. you end up setting error reporting to string so it sets it to 0 ( (int)"blabla"===0 )

use

```
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I output the $class in my autoload and figured out that I forgot a slash in the path. For some reason, error_reporting(-1) or error_reporting(E_ALL % ~E_NOTICE) don't show a single error even when doing include("faaaaaaaaaaaaaakepath.php")

Comment: Maybe you forgot to `ini_set('display_errors', 'on')` and set `show_startup_errors = On` in your php.ini